# READ ONLY pop-up when opening Access mdb, but in fact it is not according to Properties

Tags: ms-access, readonly, ms-access-2003

Any idea on why I open certain MS Access mdb file(abc.mdb), msgbox pop-up saying that it is READ ONLY, but in fact it is not when I right-click the mdb to view "Properties"?

1. The folder where mdb locates can write folder/txt files in it.
2. I copy a dummy mdb file into that folder and this READ ONLY msgbox does not pop-up in that dummy mdb. The READ ONLY issue seems only exist in ABC.mdb
3. I did not see any .ldb file in that folder.

Any idea on that?

Comment: Any of these http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324666 ?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions (in order):

- Check the security permissions in the File Properties dialog. Make sure Administrators or your login has full control.
- Repair and Compact the database file. Run this command:
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\MSACCESS.EXE" "DatabaseFile.mdb" /nostartup /repair /compact
- Try opening in a different folder like your desktop.
- If all else fails.. Create a new access database in the same folder and import all access objects from the Read Only database and test again.